# Mark sudden changes in prices in a dataframe time series and color them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of prices for different months and years (timeseries), 80 columns. I want to be able to detect significant changes in prices either up or down and color them differently in a dataframe. Is that possible and what would be the best approach?

```
Jan-2001 Feb-2001 Jan-2002 Feb-2002 ....
  100      30         10     ...
  110      25          1      ...
   40       5         50
   70      11          4
   120     35          2
```

Here in the first column 40 and 70 should be marked, in the second column 5 and 11 should be marked, in the third column not really sure but probably 1, 50, 4, 2...

Comment: If you can define what constitutes `sudden` with logic then I'm sure someone can help, But since you're not even sure what you want, you're unlikely to get any help.

Comment: Please read te before posting; [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question involves 2 problems I can see.

1. Printing the highlighting depends on the output method your trying to get to, be it STDOUT, file, or some program specific.
2. Identification of outliers based on the Column data. Its hard to interpret if you want it based on the entire dataset, vice the previous data in the column like a rolling outlier, ie the data previous is calculated to identify if the next thing is out of wack.

In the below instance I provide a method to go at the data with std dev/zscoring based on the mean of the data in the entire column. You will have to tweak the > < items to get to your desired state, there is many intricacies dealing with this concept and I would suggest taking a look at a few resources about this subject.

For your data:

```
Jan-2001,Feb-2001,Jan-2002
100,30,10
110,25,1
40,5,50
70,11,4
120,35,20000
```

I am aware of methods to highlight, but not in the terminal. The https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html method works in a few programs.

To get at the original item, identification of outliers in your data, you could use something like below to identify based on standard deviation and zscore.

Sample Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("full.txt")
original = df.columns
print(df)
for col in df.columns:
    col_zscore = col + "_zscore"
    df[col_zscore] = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std(ddof=0)
    print(df[col].loc[(df[col_zscore] > 1.5) | (df[col_zscore] < -.5)])


print(df)
```

Output 1: # prints the original dataframe

```
   Jan-2001  Feb-2001  Jan-2002
     100       30        10      
     110       25         1       
      40        5        50      
      70       11         4       
     120       35         20000
```

Output 2: # Identifies the outliers

```
2    40
3    70
Name:     Jan-2001, dtype: int64
2    5 
3    11
Name: Feb-2001, dtype: int64
0    10   
1    1    
3    4    
4    20000
Name: Jan-2002, dtype: int64
```

Output 3:  # Prints the full dataframe created, with zscore of each item based on the column

```
       Jan-2001  Feb-2001  Jan-2002      Jan-2001_std      Jan-2001_zscore  \
0  100           30        10        32.710854         0.410152              
1  110           25        1         32.710854         0.751945              
2  40            5         50        32.710854        -1.640606              
3  70            11        4         32.710854        -0.615227              
4  120           35        2         32.710854         1.093737              

   Feb-2001_std  Feb-2001_zscore  Jan-2002_std  Jan-2002_zscore  
0  12.735776     0.772524         20.755722    -0.183145         
1  12.735776     0.333590         20.755722    -0.667942         
2  12.735776    -1.422147         20.755722     1.971507         
3  12.735776    -0.895426         20.755722    -0.506343         
4  12.735776     1.211459         20.755722    -0.614076
```

Resources for zscore are here: 
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/standard-score-2.php